# How to convert "fully qualified class name" to hexadecimal value in watch of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I was trying to debug my program. Where I need the pointer value(address) that c1 object reference points to. But Visual Studio "watch" showcases null(instead of 0x0000000000000000) when the reference is not initialized, and shows {GenricityTutorial.Program.Customer}(instead of an address).

Note: I tried right clicking and clicking on "display hexadecimal", it only makes integer value to hexadecimal and not the pointers.

Output:
[image]

Expected:
[image]

Comment: Isn't the address of this variable above this entry that you've underlined (so 0xb62157e680)?

Comment: 0xb62157e680 is actually the address of the "c reference variable". Since c stores an address, so *&c value is address which is pointed by c.

Comment: Hi,  i am afraid that *&c value is not address which is pointed by c. `&c` is the address of c variable and `*&c` means to get the data at this address which is pointed by c. So `*&c` is equal to `c`. Here is my [test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/myZ7D.png).The obj variable is the type of class and it seems hexadecimal display doesn't work on object.

Comment: If you want to convert class name to hexadecimal value, you can use custom code to achieve it.